# Java 8 Is there a simple possibility to insert code in a method using reflections ore something else?

Tags: java, methods, reflection, insert, overwrite

Is there a simple possibility to insert code in a method from an other class which i cant edit?

this is my example class which i cant edit because im not the owner

```java
package me;

public class Test {

    public Test() {

    }

    public void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("im doing something...");
    }

}
```

and i want to have an event method in my class which is

```java
//should fire when Test.doSomething is called
    public static void onDoSomethingEvent() {

    }
```

i want to add onDoSomethingEvent(); to the doSomething method in Test.

````java
Method method = Class.forName("me.Test").getDeclaredMethod("doSomething");
            method.setAccessible(true);
            //is there something in some lib or else like this?
            //method.insert("Main.onDoSomethingEvent()");
    ```
````

Comment: Look at the javassist library and Byte buddy agent, but doing such stuff is definitely a bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is you can create a class that extends that **Test** and override **doSomething()** in your own way.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I'm aware.  I think that would be a security flaw.  But if you have access to what is generating the event you can do the following:

```java
class MyClass extends Test {
   @Override doSomething() {
     super.doSomething(); // to invoke super class method.
    //your code here
    }
}
```

Now add an instance of `MyClass` as a `listener` for that event.

Comment: the problem is that i cant edit the code which is calling the Test class
i cant say him execute the "fake test class" because i cant edit the method

Comment: Unless you can add your class as a `listener` for that event I don't believe you can do what your want.

Comment: It would not be a security flaw, there is no security if someone have access to app anyways. And yes, you can edit any code you want on JVM using java agents